json.loads can't parse valid NDJSON
I try to read a NDJSON file, but I raise the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/json2csv.py", line 5, in <module>
    json_data = json.loads(data)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The NDJSON file must be valid, I checked the contain and everything seems fine.
The goal is to convert the data to a csv file.
I have no clue were I messed up, hopefully some minor stupid mistake.
That's the code i used:
import json 
import csv  
data = "C:/Users/filename.ndjson" 
json_data = json.loads(data) 
csv_file = 'C:/Users/try1.csv' 
csv_object = open(csv_file, 'w') 
csv_witer = csv.writer(csv_object) 
header = json_data[0].keys() 
csv_writer.writerow(header) 
for item in json_data:  
   csv_writer.writerow(item.values())
csv_object.close() 

Thanks a lot!

Log the contents of data and include a minimal subset (which is tested to reproduce the problem) in the question. Mind, json.loads() expects only one object, so it doesn't work with NDJSON out-of-the-box, but your error reflects a problem at the very beginning of the file, whereas failure to understand the newline-delimited status would mean a problem when the 2nd line is seen.

Please update your question with a few sample lines from your ndjson file.

(note for purposes of evaluating duplicates that ndjson and jsonl are exactly the same thing).
